# Is there an extension in VSCode that helps you to see css boxes around html elements in the browser as you click on them in the editor?

Tags: html, visual-studio-code

[`<aside>` is selected on the editor and the boxes around the column 1 and column 2 get displayed in the browser. This isn't in VSCode, though, but I want to know if there is a similar extension in VSCode that can make this possible.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7XLQE.jpg)

[The paragraph tag is selected and it displays the box around the paragraph under Content](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wyz4t.jpg)

I searched but didn't find relevant extensions in VSCode that could make this happen.

Comment: reverse question is here: [How to highlight section in VScode live server when clicking my source code?](/q/50314288/11107541)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.